# C# Metro app Data bind Error

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I'm working on an app that displays data from XML file and displays it to itemgridview. I'm using the **split app** template. The error I get is :

```
<code>Error: BindingExpression path error: 'rim' property not found on
 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CLRIKeyValuePairImpl`2[
 [System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, </code>
```

&

```
<code>Error: BindingExpression path error: 'carcolor' property not found 
  on'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.CLRIKeyValuePairImpl`2
  [[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, </code>
```

**Xaml**(Open in new tab if its small):
    https://i.stack.imgur.com/4r467.png

The **XML** file( http://nak-tek.com/test/car.xml )

My code for **ItemsPage.cs**:

```
public async void GetXmlAsync()
{
   try
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync("Http://nak-tek.com/test/car.xml");
        var text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        XElement xmlCars = XElement.Parse(text.Result);
        IEnumerable<Car> data = from query in xmlCars.Descendants("car")
                                  select new Car
                                  {
                                      carcolor = query.Element("color").Value,
                                      rim = query.Element("rim").Value
                                  };
        itemGridView.DataContext = data;

    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

My Class **Car.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App2.Common
{
public class Car
{
    public string carcolor {get; set;}
    public string rim {get; set;}
}
}
```

Comment: can you post some xml examples as well (a couple of cars in the xaml format)

Comment: Can you try making the IEnumerable into a List using ToList() ?

Comment: Please check the property spellings. It must be same with class defination & XAML binding. Above code is working for me.

Comment: @Xyroid Are you using Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: No, but there will difference in resources only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested, but I believe you want to do the following:

```
//itemGridView.DataContext = data;
itemGridView.ItemsSource = data;
```

Comment: It didn't work in the "split" template, but worked when I created a new "blank" template. Thanks!